# Android MINUS Google?

Tags: google-play-store, 4.2-jelly-bean

On my Lava mobile, I run Android 4.2.2 as it came installed.

However, I want to remove Google completely. FWIW, I am not too pleased with the ToS and Privacy Policy of Google. Moreover, I almost don't use any Google services.

So, is there any way in which I can completely remove Google from Android?

I am a newbie. So, step-by-step instructions would be useful.

Comment: Related question:[can-you-fully-remove-google-system-apps-from-android-including-the-play-store-up](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65981/can-you-fully-remove-google-system-apps-from-android-including-the-play-store-up)

Comment: Yupp. Entire blog series on that: [Android without Google](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-1). Should answer most questions ;)