# 'Insufficient space on the device'

Tags: google-play-store, insufficient-memory, micromax-a89

So, I'm having problem downloading apps from Play Store because apparently, I have insufficient space on device. The app I want to download is of only 12.68 MB and my system storage has 113 MB, phone storage has 596 MB, and SD card has 1.46 GB available. 
I tried cache cleaning, uninstalling unwanted apps, moving the movable apps to SD card but it still won't work. 
The device I'm using Micromax Bolt A089 with a 4 GB SD card. 
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29416/my-internal-storage-capacity-is-running-low-what-can-i-do

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have to do is to delete the large apps then after installing the app reinstall the large app that you deleted because then it simply moves it to SD card sometimes by itself

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Joshua but sadly, it didn't work. Now, I don't have the large app I deleted, nor the small one. Can you suggest something else?

Comment: Hi Anna, you could try getting a larger SD Card like an 8GB or uninstall updates and themes if you dowdownloaded any.

Comment: You could also try manually updating the software like version wise

Answer (score 0):

Use a cleaning application like [clean master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard&hl=en) to clean junk from your device, then move as much applications to sd-card to alleviate device storage (clean master does that too).
If you're rooted try removing system applications that you are no using

[Can you fully remove Google system apps from Android including the Play Store updates?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65981/can-you-fully-remove-google-system-apps-from-android-including-the-play-store-up)